# Hide blocks on page not found in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I have google adsense in a block, and I want to hide the block when the page is a "Page not found" error page. It's against adsenses TOS to show their ads on error pages.
I figure there must be a way to write a php script to put in the Page specific visibility options. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose specific pages to be shown on errors if you go to /admin/settings/error-reporting

You should be able to use the block path settings so exclude a block from being used on of those pages.

Comment: Is there a way to make blocks visible in a custom errorpage? I used the blocks 404 module before, but it doesn't work with custom pages.

Comment: It works for me too, just not with a custom errorpage. The module doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom error page and call it 404.htm and 403.htm and make those listed as 'Do not show on' paths.

You can do this through Settings > Error Reporting